# Get value using ng-model with append - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Upon pressing add button in myform, I want to get the value in the input Name using ng-model. I am using append in my form to add the next column.
However, I am facing issues in achieving this through the code below

```js
function add(){
var stre;
stre="Name: <input type='text' ng-model='Name'><br>"
+"Result Name: <input type='text' value={{Name}}>"
$("#test").append(stre);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="test">
<button type="button" onclick="add()">add</button><br>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about `ng-repeat` ?

Comment: Then how to get value in input? can u make example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `ng-repeat` instead of `append`

*The [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given loop variable is set to the current collection item.*

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myController', myController);

function myController($scope) {
  $scope.elements = [];
  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.elements.push({});
  };

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    <div id="test">
      <div ng-repeat='elem in elements'>
        Name:
        <input type='text' ng-model='elem.name'>
        <br>Result Name:
        <input type='text' value={{elem.name}}>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <button type="button" ng-click="add()">add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/u9f9a3nn/1/)